# Upload File by API when using Docker

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am writing a spring boot application that has a PostgreSQL database. I have an API in my controller that gets a file as

> @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file

and saves the file in a folder in the project's root folder. but when I'm using docker after calling the API no file is being saved in any folder or maybe I don't know where it is saved in the container. I am using docker-compose for running the project and here are my application.properties and docker-compose.yml files:

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=postgres

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myDB?useSSL=true
spring.datasource.username= myusername
spring.datasource.password= mypassword
    
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update


## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# All files uploaded through the REST API will be stored in this directory
file.upload-dir=E:uploadedFilesOfMyProject
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  API:
    image: 'myJar.jar'
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      PostgreSQL:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://PostgreSQL:5432/myDB
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=myusername
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=mypassword
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

  PostgreSQL:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
      - POSTGRES_USER=myusername
      - POSTGRES_DB=myDB
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U myusername"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

I have set the directory as follows in the application.properties and when I use postman to upload  files, nothing is saved in this folder when the project is running by docker-compose up

> file.upload-dir=E:uploadedFilesOfMyProject

where am I doing wrong? what did I misunderstand?

If anyone could help me I would be very appreciative.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I'm facing Multipart file 'file' not found while using docker. Program works fine if I run it uncontainerized.

Comment: @sanjeev I think I solved the issue by defining volume in the docker file.

Comment: @sanjeev when you encounter a question that you are facing the same issue you can help the question view more times by rating it

Comment: yes thank you. I totally forgot to upvote the question. Could you please post the solution as an answer? Like: what path did you mount? Was it temp location etc? please.

Comment: @sanjeev I posted the final docker-compose file I have used, I don't know your exact problem but I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the final docker-compose.yml file I used: I hope it will help others too:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  pg_db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 
      POSTGRES_DB: 
    networks:
      - product-net

  api_service:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - pg_db
    networks:
      - product-net

networks:
  product-net:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  pg_db:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have to define the environment "uploadedFilesOfMyProject" in your composer file for your application.

Regards, Josef

Comment: thank you for your response but unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: How do you build you image "myJar.jar" ? Sure that this works as you expect?

Comment: First I've created the jar using mvnw install -DskipTests then I built my image using this docker file

FROM openjdk:11
ADD target/myJar.jar myJar.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","myJar.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080

then using docker build -t myJar.jar .